# How can I write an automated test for Android, if the test depends on the device?

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, tdd

What is the best approach to write a test, when its outcome depends on the target device?

For example, lets say I have an Android application whose only functionality is to display back the height of the display in pixels. How can I test that if the result will change for every different type of device?

Right now, my idea would be to test the program with three or four different configurations. Since I know what the output should be for those tests, then I need to just compare the expected value with the actual value for each device.

However, what is the correct structure for such test? Do I need to create a test class for each device? How can I run some tests only for certain test configurations? (For example, if the tests are executed on a Nexus, execute test A, but if the tests are executed on a Samsung do test B).

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your first question, if your application is for example displaying the height of the screen, obtain it using different methods and compare the results. You can use `adb shell wm size` or obtain a screenshot of the device and then obtain the image size.

And for you second question, if you create tests that are only applicable to a device you can use JUnit4 [Assume](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assume.html) which is a set of methods useful for stating assumptions about the conditions in which a test is meaningful.

A failed assumption does not mean the code is broken, but that the test provides no useful information, then you can use it at the beginning of your tests

```
@Test
public final void testSomething() throws IOException {
    assumeThat(Build.MANUFACTURER, is(equalTo("samsung")));
    // your test here
    ...
}
```